# Apply lightly transparent mask on top of image with known co-ordinates

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have the coordinates stored in this fashion in the x-axis, and y-axis.

```
rects= [[715, 49], [716, 49], [711, 50], [712, 50], [713, 50],...]
image= cv2.imread("some_image.jpg")
```

How can I add a lightly transparent colored layer to the co-ordinates stored in `rects` onto the `image` similar to the blue layer on top of the car in the following?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one option, to be optimized (*).

Define a white mask like your image, then draw polygons on it based on your segmentation data:

```
mask = np.ones_like(img) * 255
points = np.array([(320, 40), (450, 350), (250, 350)], np.int32)

color = (0, 255, 255)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [points], color)
```

Now you have a white mask with a yellow triangle, multiply the image by the mask then normalise:

```
img_with_overlay = np.int64(img) * mask # <- use int64 terms
max_px_val = np.amax(img_with_overlay) # <-- Max pixel alue
img_with_overlay = np.uint8((img_with_overlay/max_px_val) * 255) # <- normalize and convert back to uint8
```

This is what I get with an image of Paris:

[image]

---

You can also change the color depending on the class of your object and add a contour line:

```
points = np.array([(100, 150), (150, 250), (100, 300), (50, 250)], np.int32)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [points], (200, 255, 200))
cv2.polylines(mask, [points], True, (100, 200, 100), 2)
```

And get:

[image]

---

(*) Normalization can be rewritten using [cv.normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd):

```
img_with_overlay = cv2.normalize(np.int64(img) * mask, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
```

Comment: thanks for this, when you say"to be optimized" which part are you referring to and what is it that needs to be optimized?  and how do you think it should be optimized ?

Comment: very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Create a same sized cyan colored image
- Create an image that blends the two colors
- Create a white on black mask showing where you want the cyan color on the image
- Combine the original and blended image using the mask to control where each should show
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

# create cyan image
cyan = np.full_like(img,(255,255,0))

# add cyan to img and save as new image
blend = 0.5
img_cyan = cv2.addWeighted(img, blend, cyan, 1-blend, 0)

# create black image for mask base
mask = np.zeros_like(img)

# define rectangle for region where want image colorized with cyan
x1,y1,x2,y2 = 100,100,200,200
mask = cv2.rectangle(mask, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,255,255), -1)

# combine img and img_cyan using mask
result = np.where(mask==255, img_cyan, img)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('cyan', cyan)
cv2.imshow('img_cyan', img_cyan)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('lena_rect_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('lena_plus_cyan.jpg', result)
```

Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]