# how to make the mask transparent

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My program gets a face image as input then detects eyes and mouth, After that, it separates the detected parts and places them on a mask with a larger size. The output is going to be something like a Snapchat filter.
**The problem is that the mask is not transparent**

What does my code need to make the mask transparent?
i searched a lot but i couldn't fix that.

here is my code:

```
import cv2
import time
from OpenVtuber.TFLiteFaceDetector import UltraLightFaceDetecion
from OpenVtuber.TFLiteFaceAlignment import CoordinateAlignmentModel

lip_index = [52,55,56,53,59,58,61,68,67,71,63,64]
left_eye = [89,90,87,91,93,96,94,95]
right_eye = [39,42,40,41,35,36,33,37]

fd = UltraLightFaceDetecion("OpenVtuber\weights\RFB-320.tflite",conf_threshold=0.88)
fa = CoordinateAlignmentModel("OpenVtuber\weights\coor_2d106.tflite")

img = cv2.imread("face.jpg")

orange = cv2.imread('orange.png')
orange = cv2.resize(orange,(160,221))

color = (0, 0, 255)

start_time = time.perf_counter()

def big_img(img,indexes):
    
    boxes, scores = fd.inference(img)
    for pred in fa.get_landmarks(img, boxes):
        landmarks = []
        for i in indexes:
            landmarks.append(pred[i])
        landmarks = np.array(landmarks,dtype=int)
        print(landmarks)

    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(landmarks)

    mask = np.zeros(img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask,[landmarks],-1,(255,255,255),-1)
    mask = mask // 255
    result = img * mask

    result = result[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    result_big = cv2.resize(result,(0,0),fx=4,fy=4)
    print(time.perf_counter() - start_time)

    return result

lip = big_img(img,lip_index)
lip = cv2.resize(lip,(75,28))

eye_r = big_img(img,right_eye)
eye_r = cv2.resize(eye_r,(45,19))

eye_l = big_img(img,left_eye)
eye_l = cv2.resize(eye_l,(45,20))

# masking 
mask = np.zeros([121, 100, 3])
mask[0:19, 0:45 , 0:3] = eye_r
mask[0:20, 55:105,0:3] = eye_l
mask[46:74, 16:91,0:3] = lip



x, y, w, h = [60, 100, 106, 121]
orange[y:y+h, x:x+w] = mask

cv2.imwrite('result.png',orange)
```

the input images:

https://postimg.cc/gallery/7VSfYNj

Comment: How do you want  apple on face or face on apple?

Comment: @toyotaSupra eyes and mouth on a fruit. eg: https://postimg.cc/LhMgYQL0

Comment: You need to crop image from human.

Comment: Use np.where(mask==0, orange, face).  See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177320/apply-lightly-transparent-mask-on-top-of-image-with-known-co-ordinates/63178313#63178313 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74740521/combining-foreground-png-image-with-jpg-background/74746953#74746953

Answer (score 0):

There is no Alpha channel in your code so far, you should create and work with 4-channel images, BGRA, not just 3 BGR, and to blend them with a multiplication.

The sample image with the apple also has a smooth transition with the background image. If you want this, one way is after the mask is created to do Gaussian or other blur over the mask/alpha channel - if it is just 0/255 so far, it will become smooth around the edges.

Alpha-Blending:
https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-alpha-blending-and-masking-of-images/

Blur:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-numpy-alpha-blend-mask/